# How to create a list of symbolic variables?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to use n variables $$alpha[[i]]$$
(i goes from 1 to n).

I use these variable inside of a function :

```
SixJ1[j1_, j2_, j3_, j4_, j5_, j6_] := Module[{j},
  j = {j1, j2, j3, j4, j5, j6};
  Sum[alpha[[k]]*j[[k]]*(j[[k]] + 1)*
     SixJSymbol[{j1, j2, j3}, {j4, j5, j6}] + 
    beta*opVolume[j1, j2, j3, j4, j5, j6], {k, 1, 6}]
  ]
```

The problem is that when I call this function, mathematica answers me :

```
"Part specification alpha[[1]] is longer than depth of object."
```

I think it is because I never initialised thoose variables but I want to keep them symbolic.

How to avoid these errors ?

Comment: How about `alpha[k]`?

Comment: I thought that to call an element of a list we needed two bracket : [[ ?

Comment: Ok, how about `alphalist = Array[k, 6]; alphalist[[k]]`? (You have to name your variables somehow first.)

Comment: In fact your first comment intrigued me. What is the difference between alpha[k] and alpha[[k]]. I know the second is interpreted as en element of a list but I did'nt know we could only use one bracket. What mean exactly the first expression alpha[k] ?

Comment: Oh in fact it is just the function notation...

Comment: `alpha[1]`, `alpha[2]`,... is a common way to create "indexed" variables.  You can use the expression like a variable.  It's a common way to code many variables that more or less have a related meaning. It's also a way to create `n` variables when you don't know until run-time whether `n = 3` or `n = 6` and so forth.

Comment: Thank you. So as I need to create n variables I can use alpha[k] to use them. Thank you a lot !

Comment: See [`Making Definitions for Indexed Objects`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative:

```
 alpha = Table[Symbol["alpha" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, n}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ToExpression[Table[TemplateApply["alpha<*i*>"], {i, 5}]]
```

> `{alpha1, alpha2, alpha3, alpha4, alpha5}`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most elegant way that solves your problem, in my opinion, is the following one:

```
Subscript[alpha, #] & /@ Range[10]
```

or

```
Table[Subscript[alpha, i], {i, 10}]
```

If you want to create a list of "indexed" symbols, you can do it as:

```
ToExpression["alpha" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[10]
```

Or you can do something like:

```
alpha[#] & /@ Range[10]
```

, which is actually same as:

```
Table[alpha[i], {i, 10}]
```

`[[]]` - this is [Part[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html?q=Part), so you can't really use this for indexing.